# Pycharm and python command line output shows different results when running unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

When running python script in pycharm and in command line, the results are different. Why and how do I fix it?

I'm running unittest with two tests, expected one to pass and one to fail:

```
import unittest


class TestSum(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_sum(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum([1, 2, 3]), 6, "Should be 6")

    def test_sum_tuple(self):
        self.assertEqual(sum((1, 2, 2)), 6, "Should be 5")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

pycharm output:

```
Testing started at 22:53 ...
"C:\Users\python\pyrequests\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.5\helpers\pycharm\_jb_unittest_runner.py" --target test_sum_unittest.TestSum.test_sum_tuple


Ran 1 test in 0.000s


Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_sum_unittest.TestSum.test_sum_tuple in C:\Users\python\pyrequests
OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Powershell output:

```
PS C:\Users\python\pyrequests> python .\test_sum_unittest.py
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_sum_tuple (__main__.TestSum)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test_sum_unittest.py", line 11, in test_sum_tuple
    self.assertEqual(sum((1, 2, 2)), 6, "Should be 5")
AssertionError: 5 != 6 : Should be 5

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: *How* did you run it in PyCharm? It seems like you only ran *one* of the tests - try using the Run menu, or the green "play" button at the class level, to run *all* of them.

Comment: I ran with Ctrl + shift + F10